# Different values in /cmd_vel/angular/z and /odom/.../angular/z

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, odometry, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am new in the use of ROS.
I'm using simulation with model p3dx in ROS Indigo and Gazebo 2.x in Ubuntu 14.04 64bits.
I'm struggling with the difference between:
a) the cmd_vel.angular.z values (value sent to the robot) and
b) the odom.twist.twist.angular.z (value obtained from odometry), **after stabilize** the speed, exacly as link image:
[link text](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_slYV4s5-q9N1JPRzZ3alg2RWs)

In the model p3dx using the differential-drive library, for which the sending angular velocity values (cmd_vel / angle / z).
I wonder if this can be solved with configuration or is a platform of error.

Below the library insertion section in "pioneer3dx.gazebo":

```
  <!-- differential drive -->
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>100</updateRate><!-- original = 100 -->
        <leftJoint>base_right_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
        <rightJoint>base_left_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeparation>0.39</wheelSeparation>
        <wheelDiameter>0.15</wheelDiameter>
        <torque>5</torque>
        <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
        <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
        <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
        <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226287/different-values-in-/cmd_vel/angular/z--and-/odom/.../angular/z/) by [softelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25913/softelli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-02-11**:
What kind of different data? You're dealing with real values here.

**Comment by [softelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25913/softelli/) on 2016-02-11**:
I did not talk about "different data", but different values (angular speed) - as shown in the picture of the reported link. In the first, the angular velocity sent by control to cmd_vel is 0.385, while odometry returns 0.550 even after stabilize for PID joints action.

**Comment by [softelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25913/softelli/) on 2016-02-11**:
This also happens in the other two commands sent to cmd_vel. These values are also displayed in "rostopic echo". I think it can be fixed by some hidden configuration or is the problem Gazebo or drive-differential library.

**Comment by [softelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25913/softelli/) on 2016-02-11**:
I'm doubling the discussion on [gazebosim-12559](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12559/different-values-in-cmd_velangularz-and-odomangularz/)

**Comment by [softelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25913/softelli/) on 2016-02-11**:
I found this issue https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/327 and this video https://youtu.be/6WTu-mJ8Ukc which maybe related.

**Comment by [softelli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25913/softelli/) on 2016-02-11**:
By suggest of another user, I change Gazebo 2.x to 6.5.1. But the offset remains as links above:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_slYV4s5-q9clo3X1NHVl9Ud0E
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_slYV4s5-q9WXNQTk9IUUlnUG8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like the differential drive kinematic properties specified in the Gazebo plugin parameters (wheelSeparation and wheelDiameter) could be different from the actual values of the simulated robot model.

I would look at the URDF model of the robot and make sure that the actual wheel radius and separation distance match what you're putting in to the plugin.  If they are different, the plugin will compute incorrect wheel speed commands, which would result in the discrepancy you're experiencing.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2